# Missing artifacts in bitbucket steps

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have a simple pipeline deploys a Symfony app to an Azure app service after generating build assets in two steps through composer and yarn.

However, the server doesn't have the vendor folder generate by composer and webpack files generated in the node step are also missing.

I have looked at the multiple questions and documentation, my pipeline file doesn't seem to be veering off from the expectation.

Here is the pipeline file

```yaml
pipelines:
  branches:
    main: 
      - step:
          name: Build
          image: composer:2.6
          script:
            - composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-scripts --no-dev
            - ls -l $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR
            - echo "Installing composer dependencies complete"
          caches:
            - composer
          artifacts: # defining the artifacts to be passed to each future step.
            - vendor/**
            - public/**
      - step:
          name: Frontend assets
          image: node:20.9.0
          caches:
          - node
          script:
            - yarn add --dev @symfony/webpack-encore
            - yarn run encore production 
            - ls -l $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR
            - echo "Installing yarn dependencies complete"
          artifacts:
            - public/**

      - step: &deploy-production
          name: Deployment
          deployment: Production
          script:
            - ls -l $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR
            - sudo apt-get update
            - sudo apt-get install zip
            - zip -r bundle.zip  . -x *.git* *.yml *.env
            - pipe: atlassian/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.1.0
              variables:
                AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
                AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
                AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
                AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP
                AZURE_APP_NAME: 'my-app'
                ZIP_FILE: 'bundle.zip'
```

I would appreciate your help in getting past this blocker.

Comment: Does it say there is artifacts it packed in the pipeline logs?

Comment: Yes, we seem do have downloadable artifacts from the artifacts log tab

Comment: Does it appear to load the artifacts in the setup phase in the required step? Are the expected paths where you need them to be the same where the artifacts are saved from?

Comment: Thank you for the questions, I didn't realise that there's messages in the set-up.  I can see artifacts downloading in both steps